# How to wrap image tag into div for post only?

Tags: plugins, posts, functions, theme-development, images

I have created a function it wraps all image tag inside a div, but I want to apply it only for the post but my function wraps the page images inside a div also.

```
// Wrap  img into div
function wrapDivToImage($content) {

    $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';   
    $replacement = '<div class="well text-center">$1</div>';    
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);   
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'wrapDivToImage');
```

And my second query is how stop wrapping div to image tag if image tag has an attribute **id="nowrap"** even it is a post?

Answer (score 0):

You have the global `WP_Post` object available so you can look the post type like this:

```
function wrap_post_images_to_div( $content ) {
    if ( get_post()->post_type === 'post' ) {
        $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';   
        $replacement = '<div class="well text-center">$1</div>';    
        $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wrap_post_images_to_div' );
```

You can use the `preg_replace_callback` instead to filter the matches with certain ids from the matches.